# SharePoint notify new items to list

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I'm creating a SharePoint hosted app with two pages: **default.aspx** and **admin.aspx**.

When I update the list in the appweb through a function in **default.aspx**, I want that a notify windows will popup to the client that are watching the **admin.aspx** page, that a new items is added to the list.

Is that possible in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the REST API, with jQuery Ajax to get the items from the list.

- At the page load, save the ID of Top-1 item when queried descending on Created date.
- Now all you need to do is query the list every 10 seconds through REST, and see if the top 1 item you get has a new ID or not. If it has, give a popup on the page.

This is just a basic setup for getting notified when a new item is added. You would probably want to make the logic more robust by taking care of scenarios where more than one items are added to your list within 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution I think, refresh the admin site let's say every 5 seconds. If something new showed up in the list (or anywhere you want to put the data), you can show popup.

Comment: I dont want to do that, because if the person working with the admin site, or the list , I dont wont to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really looking for here is an event receiver, which of course isn't going to be supported by client side code and therefore normal SharePoint hosted solutions that don't involve pinging your list every 10 seconds aren't going to work. You *could* set this up as a provider-hosted solution, although the way they work (SharePoint will try to contact the provider 3 times when the event is fired and eats the request if it can't) means you absolutely do *not* want to write them on the -ing side of the event (really, you should be conducting any validation through the client anyway in most cases) and even for the -ed events you have to assume that you won't get all of them back.

It's not exactly what you're asking for, of course, but alerts do still exist and will accomplish about 90% of what you're looking for here if your people watching the admin page have their email open at all times.